# How to use the Raycaster with a CombinedCamera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to use a Raycaster (for selection) that works fine with a PerspectiveCamera but doesn't work with a CombinedCamera.

First it seems that CombinedCamera is not supported by the Raycaster, so [among those line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.js#L7573-7580) of three.js I add this :

```
if ( camera instanceof THREE.CombinedCamera ) {
    if( camera.inPerspectiveMode ) {
        camera = camera.cameraP;
    } else if ( camera.inOrthographicMode ) {
        camera = camera.cameraO;
    }
}

if ( camera instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

...
```

So as it refers to the nested camera, however that doesn't do the trick because, I believe, the nested cameras position-quaternion-rotation are not updated ??

How can I achieve this and make Raycaster work with both Ortho and Perspective modes of a CombinedCamera ?

Comment: [JavaScript code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html). Always include a block (i.e. "{//code}") with your if statements.

Comment: @jeum were you able to make this work ?

Answer (score 3):

The renderer needs world matrix data for the raycasting to work. Make the following modification to the CombinedCamera code:

```
  // Add to the .toPerspective() method:
  this.matrixWorldInverse = this.cameraP.matrixWorldInverse; //
  this.matrixWorld = this.cameraP.matrixWorld;               //

  // and to the .toOrthographic() method add:
  this.matrixWorldInverse = this.cameraO.matrixWorldInverse; //
  this.matrixWorld = this.cameraO.matrixWorld;               //
```

r73.